# android - Лесенка..?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, я делаю игру "Найди пару цифр". В главной роли `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`. Поле 6*6 фишек. Использую свою модель для каждого айтема. В игре я управляю состояниями фишек и обновляю `RecyclerView` с помощью `notifyItemChanged()`. Отключил анимации, встроенные в библиотеку, чтобы не мешали. Вот мой класс для фишки

```
public class Chip
{
public static final int CHIP_HIDE = 0;
public static final int CHIP_OPEN = 1;
public static final int CHIP_CLOSED = 2;
public static final int CHIP_UP = 3;
public static final int CHIP_NO = 4;

int number, drawable, textColor, state, offset;

int[] drawables = {R.drawable.bg1, R.drawable.bg2, R.drawable.bg3, R.drawable.bg4};
int[] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE};

Chip(int number){
    this.number = number;
    this.drawable = drawables[number - 1];
    this.textColor = colors[number - 1];
    this.state = CHIP_NO;
}

int getNumber(){
    return number;
}

int getDrawable(){
    return drawable;
}

int getTextColor(){
    return textColor;
}

int getState(){
    return state;
}

int getOffset(){
    return offset;
}

void setOffset(int offset){
    this.offset = offset;
}

void setState(int state){
    this.state = state;
}
}
```

Фишка состоит из цифры. Именно её я передаю в конструктор. В модели в зависимости от этой цифры создаётся фон (всего их 4) и цвет текста. При создании фишки ей даётся состояние `CHIP_NO`. Так же я реализовал методы геттеры и с ними в адаптере создаю игровое поле.

При открытии фишки я меняю состояние на `CHIP_OPEN`, при закрытии `CHIP_CLOSED`, при удалении `CHIP_HIDE`.

Решил добавить анимацию "лесенка" перед началом игры (подобно точкам на экране блокировки графического ключа. Сначала появляется верхняя левая фишка, затем та, что правее и ниже и т.д до нижней правой фишки). Для этого я создал ещё одно состояние `CHIP_UP` и двумерный массив (матрица 11*6). Вот таким циклом я прохожу по массиву и меняю состояния у фишек.

```
(new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    for(int x = 0; x<ar.length; x++){
                        for(int y = 0; y<ar[x].length; y++){
                    list.get(ar[x][y]).setState(Chip.CHIP_UP);
                    list.get(ar[x][y]).setOffset(x*1000);
                    Message msg = h.obtainMessage(UPDATE, ar[x][y],0);
                    h.sendMessage(msg);

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "["+x+"]["+y+"] = " + ar[x][y]);

                }


                }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }


})).start();
```

В зависимости от `x` я кидаю в класс модели задержку перед началом анимации, чтобы все фишки не анимировались одновременно. В адаптепе я ставлю анимации `offset` и запускаю. Но фишки все-равно появляются все вместе. Что не так?(

Вот такой порядок появления фишек

```
1
2,7
3,8,13
4,9,14,19
5,10,15,20,25
6,11,16,21,26,31
12,17,22,27,32
18,23,28,33
24,29,34
30,35
36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еле-еле накопал. Не надо никакого порядка, все просто. Делаю так

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.chip_up);
GridLayoutAnimationController controller = new GridLayoutAnimationController(animation);
controller.setOrder(LayoutAnimationController.ORDER_NORMAL);
controller.setDirection(GridLayoutAnimationController.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT | GridLayoutAnimationController.DIRECTION_TOP_TO_BOTTOM);
controller.setColumnDelay(0.2f);
controller.setRowDelay(0.2f);
recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

Все!

Answer (score 0):

```
     for (int x = 0; x < ar.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ar[x].length; y++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list.get(ar[x][y]).setState(Chip.CHIP_UP);
            list.get(ar[x][y]).setOffset(x * 1000);
            Message msg = h.obtainMessage(UPDATE, ar[x][y], 0);
            h.sendMessage(msg);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[" + x + "][" + y + "] = " + ar[x][y]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Пробовал, в этом случае фишка показываются то по три, то две, то по одной. Интересная штука. Кстати засыпать надо не при каждом изменений а при каждом прохождении столбца матрицы

Comment: что выходит, когда засыпаете между for'ами?

Comment: Приложение просто зависает и после того как отвиснет так же открывает все фишки разом

Answer (score 0):

как вариант выйти к результату, без критики по количеству строк.

```
 private void setProperties(int num){
    list.get(num).setState(Chip.CHIP_UP);
    list.get(num).setOffset(num * 1000);
    Message msg = h.obtainMessage(UPDATE, num, 0);
    h.sendMessage(msg);
}

 private void setSleep(long i){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

а цикл ниже вместо двух ваших

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 37; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i);
        }
        else if (i == 2) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5));
        }
        else if (i == 3) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            setProperties(i + 10);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10));
        }
        else if (i == 4) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            setProperties(i + 10);
            setProperties(i + 15);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15));
        }
        else if (i == 5) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            setProperties(i + 10);
            setProperties(i + 15);
            setProperties(i + 20);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20));
        }
        else if (i == 6) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            setProperties(i + 10);
            setProperties(i + 15);
            setProperties(i + 20);
            setProperties(i + 25);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20) + " , " + (i + 25));
        }
        else if (i == 12) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            setProperties(i + 10);
            setProperties(i + 15);
            setProperties(i + 20);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15) + " , " + (i + 20));
        }
        else if (i == 18) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            setProperties(i + 10);
            setProperties(i + 15);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10) + " , " + (i + 15));
        }
        else if (i == 24) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            setProperties(i + 10);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5) + " , " + (i + 10));
        }
        else if (i == 30) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            setProperties(i + 5);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i + " , " + (i + 5));
        }
        else if (i == 36) {
            setSleep(100);
            setProperties(i);
            Log.i("TAG", "i :   - " + i);
        }
    }
```

к сожалению, не могу проверить у себя

Comment: Не вижу причины делать такой цикл. Кстати, я только что заметил что дело в самой задержке перед анимацией. Я просто её ставлю программно в зависимости от позиции и ничего не меняется. Вообще не пойму как это сделать( Не знаете, где можно найти код экрана блокировки в Android Lollipop?

Comment: [код экрана блокировки в Android Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lock+screen+code+in+Android+Lollipop)